# Very tricky nonogram - where to go next?

Tags: grid-deduction, nonogram

I've become somewhat addicted to Simon Tatham's "Pattern" (nonogram) puzzles recently. I thought I was becoming fairly adept with them, but [this unusually difficult one](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/js/pattern.html#15x15:1.1.4.2/3.4.1.1/3.4.1/3.1.5/1.2.3/3.4.2/5.4.1/7.2/1.5.1/4/4.5/2.7/3.1.3/3.1/4/4/1.3/4/4.3.2/3.7/3.4.1.1/4.2/4.3.3/3.2.1.2/3.3.1/8.2/1.4.3/1.2.3/1.4.4/6.2) has me stumped. I've got as far as this by using the usual tricks:

[image: progress]

But now I can't figure out how to make any further progress. What am I missing?

**How can I make the next step to solve this puzzle?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duh, I got it.

> Bottom row: the lone square must be part of the 6-block, but there's not enough space for it to go all the way to the right: it must extend at least two more cells to the left.

Then

> edge cells are always useful because we can start from there to fill in whole blocks: in this case, the 5 and 3 at the bottom of the fourth and fifth columns.

I'm guessing the deductions will fall like dominoes from there ...

> [image: new grid after the next deductions]

Comment: And yep, I've now solved it completely. *facepalm*

Comment: You can infer even more about the 6. The center column is (7 2), flanked on either side by a 1 in the bottom position. Nothing can be filled in in the bottom row center column, otherwise you'll have an isolated square in the second-to-bottom row that violates (1 4 4). You can fill in two more squares to the left of the partial 6 block you show in the image, white out the bottom row center column and directly to the right of it, and place the 2 of (6 2) in the hole on the bottom right..

Answer (score 3):

At least

> on the bottom row, we know the 4th and 5th cell have to be part of the 6.

Answer (score 3):

[Edit] Darn, you got it as I was typing this.

There are the ones I saw immediately that can be filled in (the red letters, the blue ones are the blocks that show that the red ones need to be filled in).

> [image: Poorly editted image showing blocks that can be filled in]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the

> 1,5,1 column (number 9), because the bottom row block cannot house the 5, which limits it at the top of the column.

Then:

> the five block must start in at least row 3 and at most row 5, and this means rows 5,6,7 of column 9 can be filled.

Comment: OK, so the 5 must be in the upper block ... but *then* what? We don't know *exactly* where that 5 must be.

Answer (score 0):

I’m thinking

> Based on your 1 4 4 row (second from bottom), that you have a loner black square on the left side. If you continue that to the right, that should be your second set of 4.

Comment: But why would it continue to the right necessarily? It could equally well continue to the left, as far as I can see.